# Change default buttons name NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am very new to NSIS,
I created a simple installer with 2 screens,

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Page custom someName someEndmethod
Page instfiles
```

First one is a custom page (nsDialogs) and on it the default button is "install" and i have 2 questtions :

- How do i bound a method to its click event ?
- How do i change the text on that button ?

BTW - I am not using MUI .

The best reference i could found regarding the nsDialogs was the following:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html

but could not seem to find answer to those simple questions.

Thanks

Comment: nsDialogs and other custom pages are in the inner dialog area, the buttons on the bottom are not and are not really controlled by the plugin used to create the custom page. The part about calling Abort in the leave callback is documented in the main helpfile...

Answer (score 0):

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
Function MyPageCreate
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1 ; Get the handle to the button
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 `STR:$(^NextBtn)` ; The part after STR: can be any string, using the next button language string here
nsDialogs::Create 1018
pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
MessageBox mb_yesno "User clicked Next/Install, allow the page change?" IDYES allow
    Abort
allow:
FunctionEnd

Page Components
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page InstFiles
```

If you just want to change the string on the install button no matter which page it is on (The page before the instfiles page) you can change it with `LangString` instead.